# Gremlin: Filtering duplicate edges with timestamp property

Tags: gremlin

I have duplicate edges with different timestamp, need to get latest timestamped edge, am trying to get via below query. Am not able to use `.max()` as it is applicable for numbers. Is there any alternative for this?

```
g.V().has('streamPath','/local/Prod/SupportBI/Prod/Staging/Integration/Chat/MSaaSChatCompleted.ss').as('ParentStream').outE('generate').order().by('timestamp', decr).values('timestamp')
```

sample output

```
[
  "2018-07-10T20:18:57",
  "2018-07-10T20:18:57",
  "2018-07-10T20:16:39",
  "2018-07-10T20:16:39",
  "2018-07-10T20:07:51",
  "2018-07-10T16:18:56",
```

My actual query:

```
g.V().has('streamPath','/Chat/Completed.ss').as('ParentStream').outE('generate').as('Edges').map(select('Edges').inV()).as ('NextStream').select('ParentStream', 'NextStream','Edges').simplePath()
```

I'm getting duplicate edges (timestamp, jobid, id are different, reset of the properties are same). Need to take the recent edge which has the latest timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

If you have this:

```
g.V().has('streamPath','/local/Prod/SupportBI/Prod/Staging/Integration/Chat/MSaaSChatCompleted.ss').as('ParentStream').
  outE('generate').
  order().
    by('timestamp', decr).
  values('timestamp')
```

Couldn't you add `limit(1)` to that to just get the first one as you've ordered for most recent timestamps first?

As a side point, in TinkerPop 3.4.0 (not released at the time of this answer) you can use `max()` with any `Comparable`:

```
gremlin> g.V().values('name').max()
==>vadas
```